# My Windows Azure MVC3 application is slow. How can I see what's wrong?

Tags: azure

I have deployed my Windows Azure application to the cloud. Now that it's running it seems to be slow. Some pages taking up to three seconds to return and all the look ups are to table storage with direct key lookups.

It's not very significant but when I check with fiddler I see all of my web requests are resulting in Status codes 200. Even those for the CSS. Is this expected. I thought the CSS would be cached.

Getting back to the original question. When performance is slow is there a way I can work out why? I already set the solution configuration to "Release". What more is there that I can do?

Any tips / help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How's your CPU utilization during request processing?  How well does the site run from your local IIS w/o Azure?  With Azure emulator?

Answer (score 2):

For investigating the problems in production, you could try using StackOverflow's profiler to work out where the slowness is occurring - http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

For looking at how to encourage browsers to use cached content for css, js and images, I think you can just use web.config files in subfolders - see [IIS7 Cache-Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642954/iis7-cache-control) - and you should also be able to setup gzip compression.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://getglimpse.com 
Seems promising

Answer (score 0):

Put your files in the Azure storage and provide cache instructions:

[Add Cache-Control and Expires headers to Azure Storage Blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507657/add-cache-control-and-expires-headers-to-azure-storage-blobs)

If you want to do it from IIS, provide the proper HTTP caching instructions to the browser.

[Best practices for speeding up your website.](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

Anyway, you have to provide more details about what are you doing. Are you using Session? how many queries launch each page?

The fact that in your computer, with just one client (you) goes fast, doesn't mean the application is fast, you have to try with lots of users in order to ensure there is no bottlenecks, contention locks, busy resources etc.. etc..