# Is it possible to set properties on blob storage via AZ Copy

Tags: azure, cdn, azure-cdn, azcopy

We have an Azure CDN pointed at blob storage container. We upload on a regular basis new files via AZ Copy.

I can set it in many ways such as https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/azure/cdn/cdn-manage-expiration-of-blob-content but not in bulk.

Is it possible to set the Cache-Control property/meta data via AzCopy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the Cache-Control property is supported in azcopy as of May 2019
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/releases/tag/v10.1.2

Here's the corresponding release information from the link above:

> **New features**
>
> 1. Headers for Content-Disposition, Content-Language and Cache-Control can now be set when uploading files to Blob Storage and to Azure Files. Run `azcopy copy --help` to see command line parameter
>      information, including those needed to set the new headers.

Comment: [links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) can break and change over time. Please provide the relevant information here.

Comment: Why won't you just write out the commands instead of telling us to go to to azcopy --help ?

Comment: From CLI help: `--cache-control string    Set the cache-control header. Returned on download.`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the AzCopy parameters [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#azcopy-parameters), it does not appear you can set the Cache-Control property.

However, the [Azure Data Movement Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement) exposes a SetAttributesCallback which would allow you to set properties.

Comment: That is where I got to. In the end wrote a console app based on the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26319001/33