# Controlling cache in Azure static web site

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm playing with Azure Static Web Site (new feature of storage account).

This works well for servicing files. However, I didn't found where I can set cache control headers (if it's possible).

Basically, I want to set no expire cache to static bundled javascripts (hash of files are in file name), but not on html pages.

How to reach my goal ?

PS: I'm not using Azure Web Sites, but Azure static web site option of blob storage. Unless web.config are supported (but I don't think it is), do not redirect me to web.config solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Cache-Control and Expires headers to Azure Storage Blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507657/add-cache-control-and-expires-headers-to-azure-storage-blobs)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Azure Storage Explorer, there is a property named `CacheControl` which you can find in any blob properties. If you set the `CacheControl` property with a value like `max-age=100` as `Fig 1` below, you can see it whether be enabled via browser debug tools like Chrome Chrome Developer Tools `F12` as `Fig 2` below.

Fig 1. Set the value of `CacheControl` property of a blob `index.html`
[image]

Fig 2. Open Chrome Developer Tools to find my setting for `index.html` above
[image]

So you can set cache control header for few blobs via Azure Storage Explorer, or do the same in programming for a large number of blobs, as the answer of SO thread [Add Cache-Control and Expires headers to Azure Storage Blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507657/add-cache-control-and-expires-headers-to-azure-storage-blobs) said.